# Babel Error on using useEffect with Async function in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, uniswap

I'm trying to call an API and using useEffect to update the state in React Typescript Project.

The base project runs on 'react-script@4.0.3' and `typescript@latest`

I'm trying to add a new component to the Uniswap Repo -> https://github.com/Uniswap/interface

Here's my component

```
  const { account, chainId, provider } = useWeb3React()
  const [iconClicked, setIconCLicked] = useState(false)
  const [notifications, setNotification] = useState<notifI[]>([])
  const [showWindow, setShowWindow] = useState(false)
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const data: notifI[] = await PushAPI.user.getFeeds({
        user: `eip155:${chainId}:${account}`,
        env: 'staging',
      })
      setNotification(data)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (account) {
      console.log('Calling user details')
      fetchData()
    }
  }, [account])
```

The error I get

```
./node_modules/@ethereumjs/util/dist/asyncEventEmitter.js 24:41
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (24:41)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     let [data, callback] = args;
|     const self = this;
>     let listeners = self._events[event] ?? [];
|     // Optional data argument
|     if (callback === undefined && typeof data === 'function') {
```

I'm really new into working with such huge repositories, Please help me and Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you need to update your version of Babel or its configuration, it doesn't seem to understand the nullish coalescing operator (`??`) added in ES2020.

Comment: try without the try catch block in `fetchData` and see if the same error appears

Comment: @RajeshKanna - Why would that make any difference?

Comment: I found a thread that says to update `react-scripts` but when I do that a ton errors appear. Uniswap repo is using node 14 :(

Comment: If I remove the async function from the component, everything works fine. But I want to get a data from that API. Which I believe is possible only by async/await??

Answer (score 0):

Move/define the `fetchData` function inside the useEffect

for more information see: [this blog](https://devtrium.com/posts/async-functions-useeffect)